# How to set a value on a cell based on a drop down list?

Tags: excel

I would like to set a value on a cell based on what value we pick on a drop down list.

For example :

Column A contains a single cell which is a drop down list created with Data Validation.
Whenever we pick one of the tasks, an other cell on column B would tell the difficulty of the task from 1 (easy) to 5 (hard). Finally, is it possible to display a bloc of text depending on the difficulty ?
I have a dictionnary to match every task with its own difficulty. I simply need a drop down list to display any task directly instead of searching on a big table

Do we need VBA to code this ? What would we need to know to do this ? I have never coded in VBA but I'm familiar with a few programming languages (Python/Java)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: This can be done with a lookup table and [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Comment: Does it mean that if I create a table with all the values, I would just parse on it to find the difficulty associated with every task?

Comment: A more reliable way is to use `Index`/`Match` together.  Basically the same as `VLookup` but can be used in a much broader range of applications.

Comment: I've looked at it and it works very well, I just create tables which contain all the information I need and I can map every value of my drop down list.

Comment: You can try to click on the links on the "Related" Section in this page.. there is a lot of useful related question that can help..